# Android - Accessibility service

Tags: java, android, mobile, text, accessibilityservice

I have read a lot of topics about how to access notifications, but nothing about how to send a reply through accessibility service.

Is there any way to reply to a messaging notification through accessibility service?

Comment: I sure hope not.

Answer (score -1):

No there is not. The body must be at least 30 characters...